# Method like argument in function

Tags: python, r, function, pandas, methods

I want use method in python / pandas like argument in a function.
For example rolling statistics for dataframe:

```
def rolling (df, prefix = 'r', window = 3, method = 'here I wanna choose a method' ):
    for name in df.columns:
        df[prefix + name] = df[name].rolling(window).'here this method been called'
    return df
```

'mean()' or 'sum()' or whatever ...
like

```
df.rolling(2).sum()
```

I worked 95% time in R, and in R it's simple (put function as an argument or return any function ). But in python I noob. So I creating package to make things easier for me. Like:

```
def head(x,k = 3):
    return x.head(k)
```

What function in python help me to use method like argument in a function?

```
#some data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime
ibm = DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2016,1,1))

ibm2 = rolling(ibm,'rr', 5, 'sum') # something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this

```
def rolling (df, prefix='r', window=3, method='method_name'):
    for name in df.columns:
        df[prefix + name] = df[name].rolling(window).__getattribute__(method)()
    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr) with a str of the name of the method. This gets the attribute with that name from the object (In this case, a method)

```
def rolling (df, prefix='r', window=3, method='sum'):
    for name in df.columns:
        df[prefix + name] = getattr(df[name].rolling(window), method)()
    return df
```

Or you could just pass in the method. When calling it, the first argument will be `self`.

```
def rolling (df, prefix='r', window=3, method=DataReader.sum):
    for name in df.columns:
        df[prefix + name] = method(df[name].rolling(window))
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

A method is an attribute like any other (it just happens to be callable when bound to an object), so you can use `getattr`. (A default value of `None` is nonsense, of course, but I didn't want to reorder your signature to make `method` occur earlier without a default value.)

```
def rolling (df, prefix='r', window=3, method=None):
    for name in df.columns:
        obj = df[name].rolling(window)
        m = getattr(obj, method)
        df[prefix + name] = m()
    return df
```

Comment: Well, a default value of `None` would probably be a good way to catch errors.

Comment: True; I'm leaving any discussion of error handling for non-existent methods to the discretion of the reader.